# Regular expressions match not working accurately with semicolon

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, .net-4.0

I have a string of codes like:

```
0926;0941;0917;0930;094D;
```

I want to search for: `0930;094D;` in the above string. I am using this code to find a string fragment:

```
   static bool ExactMatch(string input, string match)
    {

        return Regex.IsMatch(input, string.Format(@"\b{0}\b", Regex.Escape(match)));

    }
```

The problem is that sometimes the code works and sometimes not. If I match a single code for example: 0930; , it works but when I add 094D; , it skips match.

How to refine the code to work accurately with semicolons?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this, I have tested..

```
string val = "0926;0941;0917;0930;094D;";
string match = "0930;094D;"; // or match = "0930;" both found

if (Regex.IsMatch(val,match))
     Console.Write("Found");
else Console.Write("Not Found");
```

Comment: It is working but let me see whether it performs for a variety of strings or not. Previously also it was working sometimes but failed on certain occasions.

Answer (score 1):

"\b" denotes a word boundary, which is in between a word and a non-word character. Unfortunately, a semi-colon is not a word character. There is no "\b" at the end of "0926;0941;0917;0930;094D;" thus the Regex shows no match.

Why not just remove the last "\b" in your Regex?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps I'm not understanding your situation correctly; but if you're looking for an exact match within the string, couldn't you simply avoid regex and use string.Contains:

```
static bool ExactMatch(string input, string match)
{
    return input.Contains(match);
}
```

Comment: "Contains" is not performing exact match. I tried it but it works for even when one code is at the beginning and the other at the end.